# Clearing textfield values after login submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login page inside an iframe, after i enter username and password, i press submit button which opens a new screen and takes me to my profile, but in the previous screen, the username and password remain. How do i manage to remove them?

Here's my code:

```html
<script language="javascript">
function signin(AUserID, APassword) {
var d = new Date();
document.electalogin.timezone.value = d.getTimezoneOffset();
if (AUserID == "" || APassword == "") { 
window.alert ("Please Specify Your Username and Password") }
return ( AUserID && APassword ? true : false);}

</script>

<form target="_blank" method="post" action="https://abc.school-network.net/Account/HTMLLogon" id="electalogin" name="electalogin" LANGUAGE="javascript" onsubmit="return signin(this.UserID.value, this.Password.value)" >
<input type=hidden name="timezone">
<table>
<tr><td style="font-family:Tahoma; Font-Size:11px">Username</td><td><input name="username" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-family:Tahoma; Font-Size:11px">Password</td><td><input type="password" name="Password" ></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><a style="font-family:Tahoma; Font-Size:11px" target="_blank" href="https://abc.school-network.net/Account/ForgotPassword">Lost Password?</a></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><INPUT type="Submit" value="Log On" id=btnLogin name=btnLogin"></td></tr>

</form>
```

---

In the last INPUT line after the value="Log On" bit, i tried entering the following:

`onClick="this.form.reset()"`

which seemed to work as it cleared the values in the previous screen but as the new window opened, the login page came up again.

Answer (score 0):

Add ids to both your Username and Password fields and then add Javascript at bottom of the page to select the fields and reset their content:

```
<input name="username" id="username" value="">
<input type="password" id="password" name="Password" >
```

At bottom of page:

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.getElementById("username").value = "";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "";
</script>
```

This code will run once every time the page is loaded and will reset both fields.